# Android studio custom auto Complete

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way in android studio to create custom auto complete ?
I'm beginner in jetpack compose, I'm tired of writing composable function.
If it's possible I want to create something like fun0, fun1 and fun2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built-in `Live Template` you can use. Just type `comp` and then press enter it will add the annotation alogside the function.

If you want to see it go to `File > Settings > Editor > Live Templates > AndroidCompose`